# send data from serial to client

Tags: arduino-yun

I am using Arduino Yun to send data from serial to client, and it's partially working because I only get short data delivered, while long data (like more than 100Byte) get the most of them lost.

on the other hand when I use the softwareSerial example in the IDE to send from serial to serial it works with no data lost. I am trying to do like the example as possible with the serial to client code using client.write(mySerial.read()) but not working as expected!

what am I missing? I guess client.write doesn't hold long data or is too slow to transmit. How can I solve this or even another way to achieve my point?

I am sending the data (as a file content on one time, not in sequence- it's a must) from pc using terminal Programm sscom32e. I am receiving the data as client using netcat on the same pc (Yun and PC connected with RS232-USB and are on the same network).

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <BridgeClient.h>

#define PORT 9000
// Make the client connect to the desired server and port
IPAddress addr(192, 168, 0, 100);

//not all pins on the yun are assignable as rx/tx
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

// Define our client object
BridgeClient client;

int led = 4;
bool Connected;
void setup() {
 pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

 // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
 mySerial.begin(9600);
 mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
 mySerial.setTimeout(20000);

 // Start Bridge
 Bridge.begin();
 //delay(1000);

 // Start Console communications and wait for port to open:
 //Console.begin();
 //delay(1000);

 //Console.println("Client connecting on port 9000");
 Connected = false;

 //delay(1000);
 //connectToClient();
 connectToClient();
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
 while (mySerial.available()) {

 client.write(mySerial.read());

 //mySerial.read();
 }

}

void connectToClient() {

 // is a connection currently active?
 if (!Connected)
 {
 // not currently connected, try to establish a connection
 client.connect(addr, PORT);
 delay(1000);

 if (client.connected())
 {
 // send something to the client
 client.println("hello server!");
 digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
 }
 else
 {
 connectToClient();
 digitalWrite(led, LOW);

 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why not use hardware serial?

Comment: what do you mean by hardware serial?

Comment: The `Serial` class of the arduino environment (commonly used to print to serial monitor) makes use of the chips hardware serial. In this case the communication is entirely handled by the hardware, software serial kind of emulates a serial in software which is more prone to errors. As you seem to be barely able to reproduce the problem in a consistent way, this could be worth a try

Comment: because I am using an RS232-Shield to receive data

Comment: Maybe try to first buffer a full message and then sending it as complete message in one request. Currently you are sending many 1 byte requests. Can it be, that the netcat client can not receive that many requests for whatever reason

Comment: no it's not a netcat -or in general- a connection problem(cause II tried to send big data from SD and it had no problem- but this solution wasn't also good because writing to the SD from Serial had the same problem). I tried buffering it in a string, using 
```
String content
character = myserial.read();
content.concat(character);
``` but this didn't work either to send from serial to client, although worked for serial to serial. 
I tried to buffer it in char array, but char arrays are just like 250Bytes long!

Answer (score 0):

I believe now that serial.read and client.write cann't work together at the same time efficiently. when client.write starts, serial.read stops and therefore data get lost. Now I am saving the serial.read in 3 arrays of each 255Byte, when they are full or I receive an end-marker I call client.write to send them and Serial stops anyway. This works but for max. 765 Byte data. I can't do more arrays to save the serial data due to the limited memory of the module, which means it's not the best solution right now. I will post the code for this later when I optimate it. the other Idea coming to my mind is to send orders to the serial to wait until client.write finishes and then continue receiving and so on. Is this possible? Is Serial that flexible? How could I communicate with Serial to wait and to continue?